# Converting @filename in curl to google apps script

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

Curl request in the documentation:

```
  curl -X POST -d "xls_url=https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/ukanga/forms/tutorial/form.xls" https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms
```

My apps script

```
function patchForm() {
     //Other details saved in scriptProperties
     var payload = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/.../pub? 
                   output=xlsx";
     //Published spreadsheet, I think this is essentially an xlsx file stored in a url?
     var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
     var url = "https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms/...";
     var params = {
       "method" : scriptProperties.getProperties()["method"],
       "headers": {"Authorization" : scriptProperties.getProperties()["Authorization"]},
       "xls_url": payload
        };

     Logger.log(params)
     UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers = params)
     return(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers = params));
```

}

How do I convert the:

```
     "xls_url=https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/ukanga/forms/tutorial/form.xls"
```

In the api documentation inside urlfetchapp.

Thank you, not really a programmer.

If I cant get urlfetchapp to work, is there a way to send a curl request via google script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl -X POST -d "xls_url=https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/ukanga/forms/tutorial/form.xls" https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms
  ```

#### Modification points:

- The property of `xls_url` is not existing in `params` of `rlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)`.
- When I saw your sample curl command, the value of `xls_url=https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/ukanga/forms/tutorial/form.xls` is sent as the form data.
- In this case, the method is the POST method.
- When I saw your script and your sample curl command, the URL and value are different.

When above points are reflected to the Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function patchForm() {
  var url = "https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms";
  var params = {
    method: "POST", // In this case, even when this line is removed, the POST method is used.
    payload: {xls_url: "https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/ukanga/forms/tutorial/form.xls"}
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to use `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/.../pub?output=xlsx` instead of `https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/ukanga/forms/tutorial/form.xls`, please replace it.
- In your curl command, the request header is not used. But in your script, `"Authorization" : scriptProperties.getProperties()["Authorization"]` is used. If this is required to be used, please include it to above script as follows. In this case, it supposes that your value of `scriptProperties.getProperties()["Authorization"]` is valid value. Please be careful this.

  ```
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var params = {
      method: "POST", // In this case, even when this line is removed, the POST method is used.
      payload: {xls_url: "https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/ukanga/forms/tutorial/form.xls"},
      headers: {"Authorization" : scriptProperties.getProperties()["Authorization"]},
    };
  ```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: I wasnt able to figure it out even when following your guidelines. HOWEVER, I was able to do what want. Used google form instead of KoBo Toolbox to accept files, that way I wouldnt have to convert the curl request to google script :) Thank you

Comment: @mbkm Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.